# no dependency infomation available when building a project throung maven

Tags: maven

Project source: https://github.com/parallaxinc/BlocklyProp

I'm trying to deploy it to a local server. after I cloned it and run "mvn package", error occurs.

```
 root@ubuntu:/home/tinywind/BlocklyProp-master# mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building BlocklyProp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.parallax.client:Cloud-Session-java-client:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.parallax.client:Cloud-Compiler-java-client:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.946 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-23T17:55:12-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/31M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project BlocklyProp: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.parallax:BlocklyProp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.parallax.client:Cloud-Session-java-client:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, com.parallax.client:Cloud-Compiler-java-client:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.parallax.client:Cloud-Session-java-client:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of netbeans.maven2.repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Is there any solution or suggestion, I am a PHP developer, this is my first time to deploy a java application to server.

Comment: It looks like this project has dependencies on other projects in that git repo. You need to clone and `mvn install` these as well.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved.